# How to get the argument to invoke an Expression?

Tags: c#, expression

Given the following code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString InlineEditable<T,TP>(this HtmlHelper helper, Expression<Func<T,TP>> fieldSelector)
{
    var compiledFieldSelector = fieldSelector.Compile();
    T argument = ????;
    TP value = compiledFieldSelector(argument);
    return new MvcHtmlString(GetInlineEditableMarkupInternal(helper, fieldSelector) + value);
}
```

How do I get the value for argument?

I have tried looking in the Expression.Parameters collection and that has something in it but I don't seem to be able to find that actual T that I passed in?

I'm calling this like

```
@Html.InlineEditable(x=>x.Property)
```

in a Razor view.

Comment: What do you need the argument for? You are not using the value of "value" in your return expression.

Comment: The code isn't quite finished. Updated.

Comment: There is no argument to get - in `InlineEditable(x => x.Property) `x` is just a parameter of some type, and is not bound to anything.

Comment: So I can't execute the expression to get the value of x.Property? I guess that's what I'm really asking here.

Comment: No, you can't. There is no value, it is a function from `x` of some type to `x.Property` of another type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 public static MvcHtmlString InlineEditable<T,TP>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper, Expression<Func<T,TP>> fieldSelector)
 {
     var compiledFieldSelector = fieldSelector.Compile();
     var arg = helper.ViewData.Model;
     var value = compiledFieldSelector(arg);
     ....
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that will work for some of my cases but what about sub models? E.g. if I do a foreach over a collection on Model in my View and then call this on one of the items - the above won't work unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, just realised I'd need to pass in the submodel in that case anyway! So will need a seperate overload to handle that. So this will work.